# Why does v-container of vuetify.js takes fluid property automatically at 67% zoom?

Tags: css, vue.js, grid, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify. When I use v-container, it automatically takes full width at 67% zoom of the browser while for the rest it works fine. I have not used the *fluid* property.

```
   <v-container>
        <v-card
            :ripple="false"
            class="mt-2"
            outlined
        >
    //xyz code here
        </v-card>
    </v-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Zooming out triggers CSS media-queries which set a max-width on container. One of those media-queries:

```
@media (min-width:1904px) {
 .container {
    max-width:1904px
  }
}
```